# GCM Android 4.0.4 cant get message

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the example from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) and create simple services for retrieve Token and messages from GCM.

**Class for token receive**

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    private String projectNumber = "gcm-test-xxxxx";

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {

            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(projectNumber,
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
            subscribeTopics(token);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    private void subscribeTopics(String token) {

    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }

}
```

This class works fine, I can retrieve token and do what i want with it.
I am starting this class as a service from **MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class));
    }
}
```

Also i have class for retrieving messages from GCM. This class don't work at all.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        }    
}
```

All this stuff was registered in manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="gcm_test.app">


    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
                android:exported="true"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="gcm_test.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

         <service
                 android:name=".gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
                 android:exported="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </service>

        <service
                android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
                android:exported="false">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I send messages with postman.

```
POST https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
headers
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key= keyFromGoogleDevelopersConsole
{
  "to" : "/topics/global",
  "data":{
      "message": "Hello world!!!"
  }
}
```

After send I receive 200 OK and message ID, but phone did not receive any messages.

What I am doing is wrong? How receive my messages?

I have changed SenderID to numbers from Developers Console but it did not help me. Aslo I have noticed Errors in debug console:

```
11-21 17:32:58.014  31813-31813/gcm_test.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-21 17:32:58.024  31813-31813/gcm_test.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzap
11-21 17:32:58.027  31813-31813/gcm_test.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
```

I thought this service that retrives the messages need somehow register or start. But when I run it like simple service it crashes.

Comment: If you look at the logcat output with no filters at the time you expect to receive a message, you will see a line like this: `I/GCM: GCM message gcm_test.app 0:1448134660868753%04d3815af9fd7ecd`, if the message was received by your device.  If you see this, but your GcmListenerService is not invoked, then you know you have successfully registered with GCM, but the message is not getting through to your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not registering with the correct Sender ID.  The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#senderid) explains that the Sender ID is the numerical Project Number listed at the Google Developers Console for your app's project.  The string you are using for Sender ID, `gcm-test-xxxxx`, looks like the Project ID.

On the Dashboard page at the Developers Console, your project data will include a line like this:

```
ID: jade-segment-123 (#123123123123)
```

For this example, the Sender ID is 123123123123.

**Update**:
Note also that you are not using the URL shown in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging):

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Comment: Hello, You were right from the beginning. I set wrong sender ID. But when I changed it I did not saw the messages because I apply filter to IDEA console with info level of messages. So stupid mistake =(
I did not test this Url  https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send, works fine with https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send.
Many thanks for help.