# Can not receive gcm message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I follow this most recent tutorial https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging

But my receiver does not receive the gcm message.

I am pretty sure that gcm is sent successfully, since the response from server side is

```
{
 "multicast_id":8234052701190658472,
 "success":1,
 "failure":0,
 "canonical_ids":0,
 "results":
     [
      {
       "message_id":"0:1448357690225369%9aaa71e7f9fd7ecd"
      }
     ]
 }
```

Here is my manifest

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.my.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="com.my.app.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="com.my.app.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
```

Here is MyGcmListenerService.java. However, it never be called.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
     // [START receive_message]
     @Override
     public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
         String message = data.getString("data");
         Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
         Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
     }
}
```

Here is my gcm dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Why my android app does not receive gcm?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you connected to internet and add internet permission ?

Comment: Yes, I have internet permission.

Comment: I too faced same problem with nexus devices. Try to test it in different devices if possible.

Comment: Did you add metadata:         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> ?

Comment: No. Is this necessary? @mdtuyen

Comment: yes, you are using google play services

Comment: You didn't post your code for registration.  Is it identical to the code in the tutorial?  Are you using `R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId`? A [recent similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834037/gcm-android-4-0-4-cant-get-message/33839807#33839807) was caused by not using the correct Sender ID.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.push.gcm">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.push.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.push.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.push.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.push.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".services.GCMInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.GCMListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```