# Android GCM Push notification does not receive

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am implement `gcm` using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) and message show success but I am not getting any push notification in my device. I am not sure where is the exact problem and why I do not get any kinds of notification. Below are my code which I implemented in my project so please know me to sort out such issue. 
Here is my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission
    android:name="com.example.android.pushnotificationdemo2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.pushnotificationdemo2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />

            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.android.pushnotificationdemo2.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.android.pushnotificationdemo2.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.android.pushnotificationdemo2.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Here is my activity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private ProgressBar mRegistrationProgressBar;
    private TextView mInformationTextView;
    private boolean isReceiverRegistered;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRegistrationProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.registrationProgressBar);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Log.e("On Received ","??????   ");

                mRegistrationProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);

                if (sentToken) {
                    mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
                }
                else {
                    mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.token_error_message));
                }
            }
        };
        mInformationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);

        // Registering BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver();

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        isReceiverRegistered = false;
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        if (!isReceiverRegistered) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            }
            else {
                Log.i("     ", "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is `MyGcmListenerService`

```
    public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        Log.e("onMessageReceived ","@@@@@@@@@@@@");

        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        sendNotification(message);

    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyGcmListenerService.this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: May be your device not being registered over gcm, so debug and check your device id. else check on some different device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not receive gcm message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890426/can-not-receive-gcm-message)

Answer (score 0):

I think Internet Permission is missing @Sakib Syed

Comment: should be comment.

Comment: Dont have enough reputation to comment

Comment: @Mujammil Ahmed I have done as you answer but still I not getting any notification in my device.

Comment: @SakibSyed first have you checked your device registers with GCM Server

Comment: try this for implementing GCM or new API with FCM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 0):

just check is your key is valid or not. if not then regenerate it and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add below permission in Manifiest file.

uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"

Comment: I have already added this in my manifest but still my problem has not been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line twice in your manifest, Remove one:

```
 uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```